# Faster way to trim a long character vector in R

Tags: r, string, trim

I have a big data set with around 500.000 rows. Each of them are strings. I would like to trim all rows to a fixed size.

I found this:

```
dt$rev <- strtrim(dt$rev, width=max_len)
```

However it takes too long. Is there a faster way?

Comment: If it's in a `data.table` why aren't you using `data.table` [syntax](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf)? Also, how long is "too long"?

Comment: I just found this question closed, I don't really understand why. This community is getting worse and worse. Here there is s good article to read about this [behaviour](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.2aqn8c7db)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has nothing to do with **data.table**. It's just that `strtrim()` is fairly slow.

As long as you're operating on single-width characters (i.e., characters that aren't, for instance, Chinese/Japanese/Korean), you can instead use `substr()`, which is much faster.

```
## Make a long character vector with 5 million elements
x <- rep(state.name, 1e5)

## Speed comparison
system.time(substr(x, 1, 3))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.43    0.00    0.44 
system.time(strtrim(x, 3))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  44.63    0.03   44.85

## Confirm that both methods return the same output
identical(substr(state.name,1,3), strtrim(state.name,3))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is extraordinary. I haven't look myself (I should) but it makes me wonder what is is that `strtrim()` does?  (Great answer.)

Comment: @Andrie. Ditto. I was shocked as well. Just now checked `?strtrim`, and it notes that, "Using this function rather than ‘substr’ is important when there might be double-width (e.g., Chinese/Japanese/Korean) characters in the character vector.", so I guess that's the answer. Thanks for prodding me to check that out.

Comment: Thanks you it worked much much faster!!!

Comment: @Andrie look, they closed the question